# Possible to flow content around a Grid-Item?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm laying out some content with the new CSS Grids layout module. There are several paragraphs that are 8 columns wide, and I would like to add a `figure` that's 3 columns wide, in columns 1-3, and have the paragraphs that follow it flow into the space to the right of the `figure`.

Is this possible? In the non-grid world I would simply add a `float:left;` to the `figure`. This is the behaviour I would like to mimic.

I don't know how long the paragraphs that follow the `figure` are going to be, so I can't just say "the next X paragraphs occupy columns 4-8."

Here's a [CodePen of a stripped-down example](https://codepen.io/johnbeales/pen/yzNmqm).

```css
.grid-container {
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat( 6, 1fr );
  width: 50%;
  border:1px solid #eee;
  margin: 1em auto;

}

.grid-container p {
  grid-column: 1 / 6;
}

.grid-container figure {
  grid-column: 1/3;
  background: rgba( 155, 155, 255, 0.5 );
  margin:0;
  padding: 1em;
  
  /* Hoping this will be enough to make the paragraphs after the figure flow around it, but apparently not. */
  float:left;
}

figure img {
  width: 100%;
  height:auto;
}

figcaption {
  margin-top:0.5em;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>A Floating Grid Item?</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="grid-container">
      <p>Fake Lipsum - is that even a real thing? Lipsi lipsum lipsooo doo.</p>
      <figure>
        <img src="http://38.media.tumblr.com/3a8dee9aae420a0048907c54ff701fc8/tumblr_n8m6qv50X11r238sko1_500.jpg" alt="A cat">
        <figcaption>I want the paragraph(s) below to flow around this box.</figcaption>
      </figure>
      <p>I want this to flow around the image. Please?</p>
      <p>It would be great if this would flow too, if it's not naturally below the image because of the amount of text.</p>
      <p>Again, it would be great if this would flow too, if it's not naturally below the image because of the amount of text.</p>
      <p>Yet again, it would be great if this would flow too, if it's not naturally below the image because of the amount of text.</p>
      
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please post the code you've tried. We can help you more effectively if we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Michael_B Just added a link to a stripped-down codepen.

Answer (score 2):

The text you want to flow around the fig. goes in a div and then flow the fig.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>A Floating Grid Item?</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="grid-container">
  <p>Fake Lipsum - is that even a real thing? Lipsi lipsum lipsooo doo.</p>
  <figure>
    <img src="http://38.media.tumblr.com/3a8dee9aae420a0048907c54ff701fc8/tumblr_n8m6qv50X11r238sko1_500.jpg" alt="A cat">
    <figcaption>I want the paragraph(s) below to flow around this box.</figcaption>
  </figure>

  <div class="text">
  <p>I want this to flow around the image. Please?</p>
  <p>It would be great if this would flow too, if it's not naturally below the image because of the amount of text.</p>
  <p>Again, it would be great if this would flow too, if it's not naturally below the image because of the amount of text.</p>
  <p>Yet again, it would be great if this would flow too, if it's not naturally below the image because of the amount of text.</p>
  </div>
  </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

use this CSS

```
   .text {grid-column: 3 / 6;float:left;}
```

Comment: That kinda works - it's probably the best possible answer - but my end goal is to have the text, once it's below the level of the figure, go below it as well, so the figure is surrounded by text.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [CSS Grid Specification](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-grid/#grid-containers) `float` has no effect on grid-items, so I don't think there's a great way to make this happen.

Keshav's answer is the best way to make it so a short paragraph right beside the `figure` doesn't mean the next paragraph will drop below the `figure`.

If we can be sure that the paragraph immediately following the figure is long enough to pass the figure we can do something like this with the CSS:

```
figure { grid-column: 2 / 4; }
figure + p { grid-column: 5 / 10; }
```

But it doesn't guard against having a gap between the paragraph immediately following the `figure` and the paragraph after that, and neither solution lets the text flow right underneath the `figure`.